# Web part or view that displays all 'Pending' documents within a SPSite

Tags: web-part

How would I create a web part or view that displays all 'Pending' documents within a SPSite.
Ideally it would also allow users with the correct permissions to also approve them from here too but to keep things simple I could settle for just a list.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get all the documents in multiple libraries of a site or from just one particular library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to get data from multiple libraries you can use **[SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)** to fetch all the documents with Pending status. You can refer below code to start with:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

                    //Ask for all document libraries
                    query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />";
                    // check for moderation status =2 ie Pending.
                    query.ViewFields = "";//set the fields which you want to fetch
                    query.Query = @"<Query>
                                        <Where>
                                            <Eq><FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' /><Value Type='ModStat'>2</Value></Eq>
                                        </Where>
                                  </Query>";

                    // Query all Web sites in this site collection.
                    query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

                    DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to the SP object model, now you have defined this its much easier to understand. Just need to define my DT